# JavaScript to add class not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS function:

```
function addTopLinks() {

    $('#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th .fc-resourceName')
 .addClass('top-cell');
};
```

It is not adding the class.

I have another:

```
function addDayClass() {
    $('#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th')
        .filter(function () {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf('Mon ') == 0) return true;

            return false;
        })
        .addClass('monday');
};
```

That one works just fine.

This is the hierarchy:

[image]

I am really not sure why the first one is working and not this one...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us where you call `addTopLinks`?

Comment: why are you being so specific to target fc-resourceName ?

Comment: Can't you just use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector, instead of:

`'#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th .fc-resourceName'`

try:

`'#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th.fc-resourceName'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th .fc-resourceName').addClass('top-cell');
```

should be

```
$('#calendar .fc-view-resourceNextWeeks thead th.fc-resourceName').addClass('top-cell');
```

(Note the removal of the space between `th` and `.fc-resourceName`)

The first one is looking for *another* element inside the `th` with class `.fc-resourceName`, while you actually want that element.